# Rails: respond_to vs "case" conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the advantage of using `respond_to` in Rails instead of a case statement?
I have several instance variables that I want to set same way for some formats, but not for HTML. This does not seem to work:

```ruby
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    # ...
  end
  format.any(:csv, :xml) do
    # common stuff
  end
  format.csv do
    # ...
  end
  format.xml do
    # ...
  end
end
```

I think I'll end up using a couple of `case request.format` and not using `respond_to` at all:

```ruby
case request.format
when 'html'
  # ...
when 'csv', 'xml'
  # common stuff
end
# more common stuff
case request.format
when 'html'
  # render
when 'csv'
  # custom render csv
when 'xml'
  # render xml with a template
end
```

So I wonder what is a good use case for `respond_to`, where `case request.format` wouldn't look better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`respond_to` is not just a way to find out what type of response the *client* expected but also a way to tell `rails` what type of response you are willing to provide.

For example a simple scenario where we have this controller:

```
class SimpleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to :html, :json
  end
end
```

A client sends a request expecting xml response

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/xml" \
     -X GET "host:port/simple/index"
```

Rails will response with `406`

```
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

However, if you simply filter `request.format` using `case` like in your example the client will receive a `500` error because `rails` cannot find a corresponding template to the request format.

Of course you can also call `respond_to` on **class** level as well as specify respond format in **routes.rb**

Dive into `rails` source code and api documentation if you want to get more in-depth explanation to this.

Comment: I am lazy to try it right now, do you mean that `respond_to do |f| f.html; f.json end` would also tell Rails to respond with 406 error in your example? (In your example it is `respond_to :html, :json`)

Comment: yes so respond_to take **either** `block` or array of `mime types`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the reason the `respond_to` block does not work is because you are using `format.any(:csv, :xml)` in conjunction with `format.csv`. You can only use one of these.

This should be a clear indication that you are trying to do too much in your controller. For example, if you are doing common stuff for `csv` and `xml` responses, then maybe you should create a class in your lib directory:

```
# lib/foo_serializer.rb
class FooSerializer
  def initialize(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end

  def do_stuff
    @bar.to_s
  end
end
```

And then call one of its method for each type of response:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    # ...
  end
  format.csv do
    FooSerializer.new(data).do_stuff
    # ...
  end
  format.xml do
    FooSerializer.new(data).do_stuff
    # ...
  end
end
```

The `respond_to` syntax:

1. Is part of the standard Rails Way™
2. Takes care of rendering the correct file
3. Not only looks better but is also more maintainable

You should try to stick with it.

Answer (score 2):

The `request.format` field can be useful where the `respond_to` block is not appropriate.

For example, I'm using the [sunspot](http://sunspot.github.com/) gem for searching, and my controller looks like this:

```
def index
  case request.format
  when 'xlsx'
    per_page: Person.count
  when 'html'
    per_page: 30
  end
  @search = Person.search do
    with :name, params[:name]
    fulltext params[:search_term]
    paginate page: params[:page], per_page: per_page
  end
  @people = @search.results
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xlsx {send_file @people.to_xlsx, filename: 'people.xlsx'}
    format.html
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Rails for a while, and I've always seen respond_to in this form:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
end
```

I don't know where you would've seen something with the nested do's.

EDIT:

For pagination, see

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

EDIT 2:

```
format.html { render :html => Post.paginate(:page => params[:page]) }
```

or something like that.

Comment: Ok, i agree that in this basic case it looks more concise that `case request.format when 'html' render ...` but if i want to paginate the list of records, it would seem natural to paginate only for html format, so i would put pagination inside of `format.html { ... }`.

Comment: you can use `do` and `end` instead of `{` and `}`. it's nothing unusual.

Comment: @varatis: the question is where to paginate.  To me, the most natural place is inside `format.html { ... }`, or after `case request.format when 'html'`, because pagination is only needed for html response.

Comment: I mean, if you provide us with the rest of code for your controller, I could help you out. I think my second edit should solve the problem though.

Comment: Thanks varatis, but my question is: why is it better than `case`?  I suspect that i do not understand all the advantages of `respond_to`, because i think i am going to use `case` in my application.  In particular because `case` will be readable even for people new to ruby or rails.

Comment: @Alexey I think the answer is just that it looks way more readable with respond_to. Look at the number of lines you would use for my response, versus the case format you gave.